# Mosaicing face problems in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, mosaic

Hi I am using opencv and c++. I have a left profile and a front face of the same individual. If after determining the transformation matrix between the face images and applying that transformation matrix to the left image,when I superimpose it on the original frontal face,shouldn’t it have given me a face like this [image: desired result],with everything aligned?I am obviously doing something wrong and getting this result [image]. Can anyone help with this please?Here is the link to that research paper http://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/abdi-ypaa-jmm2006.pdf

Comment: Alignment wasn't done for (all of the) marker positions (looks like top blue marker and eye position defined the transformation?).
Did you try to extract the marker positions (and their corresponding ones) manually and give that as input to your transformation computation method? That way you can check whether transformation was applied correctly. For a perspective homography you need 4 correspondences. With 3 correspondences you can find a 6DoF affine homography.

Comment: yes after finding the transformation matrix between the 2 images based on the marker points,I used affineTransform..after that I did Mat result=left_transformed/2 + front_original/2 and I get the above image.

Comment: since the markers aren't aligned in the composition, your transformation computation OR your transformation application might be wrong or not good enough!

Comment: I am doing exactly as the above paper but dont know what is going wrong. Here is an extract of how I found the TM http://pastebin.com/82psz14U

Comment: These question is usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taken the images from one of your previous questions, manually finding pixel correspondences for the green dots only (so 3 correspondences) and this code

```
//cv::Mat perspectiveTransform = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(firstFacePositions, secondFacePositions) ;
cv::Mat affineTransform = cv::getAffineTransform(firstFacePositions, secondFacePositions) ;
std::cout << affineTransform << std::endl;
cv::Mat perspectiveTransform = cv::Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64FC1);
for(unsigned int y=0; y<2; ++y)
    for(unsigned int x=0; x<3; ++x)
    {
        perspectiveTransform.at<double>(y,x) = affineTransform.at<double>(y,x);
    }

std::cout << perspectiveTransform << std::endl;

cv::Mat warped1;
cv::warpPerspective(face1,warped1,perspectiveTransform,face2.size());

cv::imshow("combined",warped1/2 + face2/2);
```

I get the following result:

[image]

using the line `cv::Mat perspectiveTransform = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(firstFacePositions, secondFacePositions);` instead and using the blue marker too, I get:

[image]

**edit**: C++ syntax, but that works with C# and Java similar I guess.

Comment: thanks ALOT!so using the green AND blue markers would deform the face?

Comment: well, both homography versions deform the face, but the 8 degree of freedom version is more sensitive to noise and since I clicked the marker positions with the mouse, that might have leaded to the bigger deformation. Periphereal regions like ears (on the correct side) will probably be positioned better with a fully perspective (8 degree of freedom) homography, but that's not what you want, since the images from the paper look more like a non-perspective transformed alignment. But I didn't read the paper, so I don't know exactly :)

Comment: but your error in your own project seems to be **one of these**:
**1.** extracting the marker positions; **2.** computing the transformation; **3.** image warping/transformation application; since even with four markers, the alignment of the markers is "ok" after warping, what's not the case in your posted image.

Answer (score 4):

The registration procedure is maybe working, but you need to define better which features you want to use for the alignment or you are using images with a deformation that is too large.

- In the small (color) image, the eyes are aligned.
- In the big (grey) image, parts of the face appear to be correctly aligned, but not the eyes (for example).

If your goal is to have eyes and mouth aligned, then you should detect them and apply some 2D (affine or homographic) mapping that aligns them with your template. if your goal is to have the green / blue points aligned, then you need to use them to feed the 2D mapping estimator, but in this case there will be no guarantee that the eyes, mouth, etc. are aligned: only the points should match.

Comment: from previous postings I guess the markers (green/blue) should be aligned.

Comment: the grey image comes from the research paper which i want to implement. The colored image is the one that I am working on. Actually, the grey image originally had marker points just like mine. But after superimposing the left profile image on the frontal face,it becomes like that. I need everything to be aligned-the marker points,the eyes,mouth,nose,etc..just like the grey picture. Here is my left image(which has been transformed with the transformation matrix found between the 2 images) http://i.imgur.com/YKTGU7m.jpg  and here is my original front face image http://i.imgur.com/2roKEkv.jpg.

Comment: everything won't be aligned perfectly with a homography since the human face is not plane. But how did you compute/find the transformation matrix?

Comment: to find the transformation matrix I found the coordinates of the marker points on the left and front face. I edited the question above and included the link to the research paper I am trying to implement

Comment: If you can link to the paper you want to implement, we may check all the assumptions directly with you.