# Error after mosaicing face in opencv and c++

Tags: c++, opencv

Following my previous post [Mosaicing face problems in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695290/mosaicing-face-problems-in-opencv) , everything was working fine until I tried it again today and I get this error [image]. Everything seems to be alright but I am confused why I am getting this error. Can anybody help please?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the *source vector* or the *destination vector* of some algorithm does not have enough data required by a particular algorithm present in imgwarp.cpp

As I have no idea of your code, I assume that you may be using getAffineTransform or perspective transform.

Probably the assertion failure must be from getAffineTransform. It must require 3 points for its input and output. Have a look at the code on how these points are selected.

As you mentioned that the code was previously working, there is a possibility that the input images are changed, mostly the new one is with a different dimension.